# Does the buckler make other shield options irrelevant?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, optimization, shield

Years ago in our group we came to the conclusion that the buckler is a shield that leads itself to help player optimization as it allows most character to have shield empowered with magical armour without actually holding the shield (similarly, but not like a shield with the +2 animated magical property, at a cheaper cost) and having less armor penalties at the cost of losing none or 1 AC. Furthermore a mithral buckler allows no spell failure (making it a great item choice for a caster)

Compared to a mithral light shield with the animated (+2) bonus a mithral buckler costs 8k gold less and offers same AC.

This belief was reinforced when we noticed that in 5e the buckler was not present.

We decided to ban the buckler from the campaign as we realised at the time that most PCs and NPCs would have had one rather than a shield.

1. Is it correct that the buckler overshadows other shield options and should be taken by most characters?
2. Was banning it therefore the correct move or should we have done something else to handle that situation?

Answer (score 8):

### Yes, a buckler is a shield

> #### Table: Armor and Sheilds
>
> | Armor | […] |
> | --- | --- |
> | ***Shields*** |  |
> | Buckler | […] |
>
> […]
>
> #### Buckler
>
> This small metal shield […]

<sup>([Armor Descriptions](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/equipment/armor.htm#armorDescriptions))</sup>

### The buckler is probably the most popular shield, but…

…it’s not *that* much better than the competition, and other shields have their uses.

For one thing, bucklers and light shields are very similar:

- Cost and weight are slightly different.
- All actual combat stats are completely identical.
- Both allow you to hold something in the same hand as the shield:

  - The buckler allows you to attack with a weapon held in the same hand (see below)
  - The light shield does not allow attacking with the held item
- Both allow you to attack with the same hand, but lose their AC bonus for a round when you do:

  - Bucklers by allowing you to attack with a weapon in that hand, but at a −1 penalty
  - Light shields by bashing with the shield itself, with no penalty but probably less damage
- Both are compatible with mithral, which is very good for either of them—but also *equally* good for both of them.

So the only significant difference is that an arm with a buckler can attack with a “real” weapon, while an arm with a light shield can only bash, but the light shield can potentially bash with the shield while holding a non-weapon, while holding a non-weapon in the buckler hand generally means not attacking with that hand. And if you weren’t planning to attack with that hand—many characters aren’t—then there is just no difference between the two shields.

As for *animated*, an *animated light shield* doesn’t make a great deal of sense. A heavy shield provides more AC, which isn’t usually worth very much, certainly not worth giving up a hand, but if you’re making it *animated* anyway, it might as well be heavy. After all, being *animated* eliminates all the advantages of a buckler or light shield in the first place. And while a *+1 animated heavy shield* is very expensive, and not worth it just for +1 AC, if you wanted to use that hand for weapon attacks, it actually gives you (at least) +3 AC as well as +1 attack over a buckler, since it allows you to retain the shield bonus to AC and doesn’t apply the −1 attack penalty that a buckler does. Debatable whether that’s worth the expense, but then again, at higher levels, the expense isn’t necessarily that much.

There is also the hide shield in *Sandstorm*, which has a +3 shield bonus to AC, and can perform the cover trick that tower shields can, but with far fewer penalties and without requiring special proficiency. This is a pretty valid shield for a lot of characters. Again, very nice target for *animated*, though it is a little unclear exactly how that works with the cover trick or the attack penalty that the shield applies.

### So you really don’t need to “do” anything about it

The buckler and the light shield are almost identical. Removing either just means everyone using it would instead use the other one; only a vanishingly small percentage of characters would ever be even slightly inconvenienced by the swap. You could ditch both, and the heavy shield would be the only game in town, which would be a lot more questionable for a lot of folks, at least until *animated* comes into play, so that’s one way to see fewer shields, but... shields were pretty universal armament in real life for a reason; I don’t really see “have fewer people use shields” as particularly desirable in itself. Is it a “good thing” that it’s so “easy” to just have a shield (and another platform for armor special properties)? I dunno, I guess that’s up to you, but I’ve never felt it was a problem.

Comment: thank you for your reply. What about wizards and sorcerers being able to access shields bonuses without spell failure risks if using the mithral buckler? Our group point of view was that as the buckler seemed a good item for any class it made no point for having it, as everyone would use it.

Comment: @Digius I am honestly confused what more you’d like me to say on that subject than I already have. The buckler and the light shield are nearly identical—particularly for sorcerers and wizards. Should almost every sorcerer or wizard have one or the other? Yes—but I’m not seeing the problem with that. There are only so many shields in the game, after all, and having a shield be a “default” if you’re not doing anything in particular with that hand seems entirely valid and realistic, to me.

Comment: @KRyan I'd be quite sympathetic to a thematic argument here - spellcasters (particularly arcane ones) with shields aren't particularly common in fantasy source material in my experience, so questioning whether the mechanics should push them in that direction is reasonable.

Answer (score 3):

The other answer by KRyan shows that light shields and bucklers are more-or-less interchangable for most spellcasters and potentially even for two-weapon fighters, but there's also an argument to be made that bucklers aren't at much of an advantage for the primary remaining style; that is, two-handed weapons.

Bucklers are the only shield that can be specifically used in conjunction with a two-handed weapon, but they apply a -1 penalty to hit.  In contrast, using a spiked heavy shield in two hands applies no penalty and provides 1 extra point of AC.  While a buckler with a two-handed weapon would generally allow for a greater damage die, most two-handed weapon users are just aiming for power attack damage and don't care about the damage die to begin with.  In this context, the increased accuracy and AC is a viable trade-off for marginally less damage.  The only major exeptions are reach weapon tripping builds and crit-focused builds, both of which would generally prefer no shield at all over taking a penalty on attack rolls or critical confirmation rolls.

In short, a large number of two-handed melee builds would prefer a heavy shield over a buckler.  With two-handed melee weapons being a fairly dominant choice for martial classes, that's a big market for non-buckler shields.

---

**As a side note**, if you do have a thematic issue with too many classes using bucklers or light shields, just restrict the world's supply of mithral.  When made out of mundane materials, these options are significantly less prominent on spellcasters.